# can't upgrade from kubuntu 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, do-release-upgrade

Currently I'm running latest version of kubuntu 19.04 disco.

Following the [EoanUpgrades/Kubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EoanUpgrades/Kubuntu), after releasing of 19.10 eoan, I've tried to upgrade my disco to eoan and so far no luck.

'sudo software-properties-qt' shows 'Normal Releases' in the Release Upgrade section under the 'Updates tab.

But 'sudo pkexec do-release-upgrade -m desktop -f DistUpgradeViewKDE' reports 'No New release found'.

Any suggestions?

```
$ sudo apt-get update
hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
hit:2 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                                    
ignore:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                   
hit:4 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease                            
hit:5 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease                          
hit:6 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                                    
hit:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/19.04/prod disco InRelease                       
hit:8 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                            
hit:9 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian disco InRelease                       
hit:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                  
hit:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease                            
hit:12 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                                   
hit:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                                      
hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease              
hit:16 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco InRelease                          
hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu disco InRelease
hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu disco InRelease
hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/quiterss/quiterss/ubuntu bionic InRelease
hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sicklylife/filezilla/ubuntu disco InRelease
Reading packages list... done

$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading packages list... done
making dependancy tree                
reading status information... done
detecting upgrade package... done
upgraded: 0 , new installed: 0 , removed: 0 , pending: 0 

$ sudo pkexec do-release-upgrade -m desktop -f DistUpgradeViewKDE
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

Comment: just a little advice: before upgrading your kubuntu installation you **must** remove oibaf ppa and use generic open source drivers, then after upgrade you will re-add the ppa. this is just to prevent serious errors when installing the update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On release date, the ISO's are made available.  It's a few days before `meta-release` is updated for 19.04 installs, which means they don't detect the availability of 19.10.

Release days are always Thursdays for Ubuntu (and flavors), however it's not usually till the following Monday-Tuesday that the *taps* or *switch* is pulled that allows existing 19.04 systems to see the 19.10 being available.  *For LTS releases, eg. 18.04 LTS this occurs a few days after the release of 20.04.1*

Yes you can use '-d` to force it, but the current system allows any bugs to be detected, get fixed by devs, before most users 'upgrade' and start using the newly released system, let alone stretching out the bandwidth hits of ISO downloads plus release-upgrades.

Give it a few days, and it'll occur as intended.

--

I'll add a comment from Erich Eickmeyer (a Ubuntu Studio developer)

> Usually, the release team waits 1-2 weeks after a release to enable
>   the upgrade notifications just to make sure that the bugs for the
>   upgrade route are ironed-out
>
> Once the release team enables the upgrade notifications, then users
>   get notified. Prior to that, users are welcome to upgrade to the new
>   release manually, but like I said, the new release notification
>   happens 1-2 weeks after the release, sometimes sooner.

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/up-to-this-day-kubuntu-still-does-not-have-the-previously-removed-release-upgrade-notification/13038in

*this wasn't the smoothest upgrade cycle; ISOs were re-spun ~90 mins after the planned release time*

Comment: Oh I see. upgrade has not been available yet...

Comment: There is no set day/date it occurs, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseSchedule provides the release schedule for 19.10/Eoan, however when the *taps* or *switch* is turned/flicked can vary on the number of issues that are noted (if a larger number of bugs are reported; it can be pushed back further) or occur earlier (ie. few issues detected).  It's enabled when everything looks good.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed supplement. understand why the upgrade is delayed from the release date.