# I cannot to get the last upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I use Ubuntu Studio 19.04, and I have the upgrading process configuration to "Any new version", but...

Even the fact that the last upgrade (19.10) is already made... I don't have any new version upgrade offering here!

What's wrong?

Or... Do I have some "manual" operation about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't upgrade from kubuntu 19.04 to 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182294/cant-upgrade-from-kubuntu-19-04-to-19-10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes about a week or two *after* release before the upgrade path that is 'automated' with the upgrade manager or `do-release-upgrade` is actually opened.  (Why this is the case I'm not sure, but I think it has to do with bug squashing and bug handling of major issues detected post-release)

Patience is your best call here.  It should be available within the next week or so.

---

If you are supremely impatient, and want to upgrade *now* however, you can try doing

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y && sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

... on the command line.  However this could result in a broken system, or an unbootable system.  So you do this at your own risk.

(The reason I don't recommend you upgrade yet until the upgrade path is open is because there may be major issues that are unfixed that will leave your system unbootable or usable post-upgrade.  You upgrade now at your own risk.)

Comment: What would `-d` flag result in? The same thing as the good release or something buggy?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix the only reason I didn't say to use `-d` is because of the overwhelming number of bugs that've been filed related to GRUB and boot issues on 19.10 thus far that I've seen on the bugs radar.  This is an intentional omission of information - I don't want OP to upgrade and be left with a system they can't boot :P  **In theory** this can put them on 19.10 if they do `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` but I can't guarantee they'll be left with a working system.

Comment: Thanks for the data!!!

Comment: Interesting [this article](https://www.debugpoint.com/2019/10/upgrade-ubuntu-19-10-from-19-04/) says to use `-c` but I'm on phone so can't validate.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix that forces do-release-upgrade to refresh if there's an upgrade or not and the 'reboot' would force the system to detect it, but that isn't actually a sure-fire solution, the only way to force it is to use `-d` - `-c` will "Check only if a new distribution release is available and report the result via the exit code" but does nothing else (pulled from the 19.04 d-r-u help output)

Comment: That is worth a +1 in itself :)