# Upgrading Ubuntu Studio from 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: 19.04, ubuntu-studio, 19.10

I am currently running Ubuntu Studio 19.04.  I would like to upgrade to Ubuntu Studio 19.10.  When I clicked the upgrade button in the Software Updater, the block that opened mentioned only updating Ubuntu, not Ubuntu Studio.  Can I use this approach to upgrade, or should I use another approach?

Comment: Have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182294/cant-upgrade-from-kubuntu-19-04-to-19-10/1182295#1182295 , which includes clue on forcing (`-d`) and the opinion of *Erich Eickmeyer* (Ubuntu Studio developer) on timing of process.

Comment: The base of Ubuntu Studio is Ubuntu, including Xubuntu desktop & ....    when enabled - all flavors are enabled at the same time as the base of all flavors is the same.

Comment: You can clone your Ubuntu Studio 19.04 to a new partition and test the upgrade on it first: [Bash script to clone active Ubuntu Partition to clone partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-backkup-clone-ubuntu-to-another-partition/1028605#1028605) I honestly can't say if the upgrade being offered to you is regular Ubuntu or Studio version. In either case the upgrade may break things and you might want to reclone and retest a few times until all the bugs are worked out.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a reboot and then 19.04 software update, informed that Ubuntu Studio 19.10 was available upgrade went smoothly.